# Symfony onKernelRequest headers->set dont received on @Route

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing, symfony-eventdispatcher

I have functionm **onKernelRequest** when i want to add some custom header(in my case `api=true`||`$request->headers->set('api', "true")`) and in all `Request $request` i can get that header but when i try it on annotation its fail:

- **onKernelRequest**:

```
public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) { return; }

    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $request->headers->set('api', "true");
    return;
}
```

- **Route**

```
/* @Route(
 *     "/user/info/",
 *     name="get_user_info",
 *     methods={"GET"},
 *     condition="request.headers.get('api')"
 * )
```

- **Error**

```
Path almost matches, but Condition "request.headers.get('api')" does not evaluate to "true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router listener is being called before your listener.

The router [https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/EventListener/RouterListener.php#L158](listener listen has a priority of 32) where as your listener has a priority of 0 (the default).

If you set your listener to have a higher priority than the router listener it should work.

<sub>An example using YAML</sub>

```
services:
    App\EventListener\YourListener:
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: kernel.request
                priority: 40
```

Comment: thanks for answer, its work but in my case i need to write `KernelEvents::REQUEST => array('onKernelRequest', 40),`